# How to stop Travis CI (.com) from building on main during pull request

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, travis-ci

My `travis.yml` accounts for running the "publish" stage only on the main branch.  Here's how i'm handling this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - name: publish
    if: branch = main
  - release
```

To my dismay the "main" branch is technically associated when a PR is opened.

[image]

This shoots a hole in my ability to only "publish" to Maven Central on *merges* to main.
So this is my main concern.  How do I refactor my `.travis.yml` to only run on merges to main?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems backwards but I figured out to use the following

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - name: publish
    if: branch = main AND type NOT IN (pull_request)
  - release
```

I tested it and it worked.  I just feel like Travis CI dropped the ball on this one.